# Issues With Sharepoint 2007 installation and stsadm restore (User)

Tags: 2007, installation, restore, stsadm

I'm used to install SharePoint with the basic option, that install SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2005 and configures almost everything, but now I need to install SharePoint using a database already installed (SQL SERVER 2005 Standard).

I installed the SQL Server successfully, and then I created an user on domain (DOMAIN\spuser), added him to Administration group (local), and told the SharePoint installation to use this user to connect to database (on SharePoint Configuration Wizard), and on the SSP installation (SSP, Mysites, etc).

The issue I'm having right now is that ONLY spuser can make restores (using stsadm), any other user, including the DOMAIN ADMINISTRATION (Domain\Administrator) gives me an access denied.

When using the Basic installation, all local administrators had this kind of access.

What did I do wrong? I've checked when doing the restore that the database GETS created (WSS_Content_XXXX), but no content is restored at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally considered bad practice to always do your installs using the Basic option (unless it's an evaluation or development system). The setup procedure basically fails to follow the "least privileges required" methodology, which leads up to the situation you currently have.

You should run the entire installation process, as well as any further configuration using an account you have created specifically for the maintainence of the SharePoint farm (sometimes called the Farm Account). Under no circumstances (on a production environment) should use the Domain Administrator account for this, as the services installed run on far higher privileges than are needed for their purposes.

To answer your question: Restart the installation procedure logged into your SPUser account.

Comment: So, just create an DOMAIN\SPUSER, set it as LOCAL Administrator, log in windows 2003 with that account, and follow the install process? And use only this account always when SharePoint asks me for an account? (SSP, search, etc).

Comment: Depends what that account is being used for. Best practice dictates that each service has its own service account. This is because you'll disable remote logon with those accounts, but of course you need remote logon available on your SharePoint install account.

Comment: The setup account should never be called the "Farm" account. The "Farm" acount is the account that runs Central Admin/Timer. And you should never run the setup as your "Farm" account.

Comment: Yup, you're right, that slipped my mind just there :) Separate installation and services accounts!

Comment: Is there a documentation about which accounts and permissions are the ideal to install sucessfully? My setup will be very basic, just one server with SQL SERVER 2005 and 1 SharePoint, no other computers will be in the FARM at all. My only questions are regarding which users and which permissions are needed. Thanks!